# IE 6 bug centering div tag with absolute positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

`<div id="outer" style="width:100%; text-align:center">`

`<div style="position:absolute; top:197px; text-align: center; width:858px; margin:auto; left: 0; right:0">`

I am using these two `<div>` tags to center a menu.  It works beautifully except in IE 6.

I looked through the other questions, tried several things but nothing worked.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First off...make sure your page has the proper DOCTYPE definition. Otherwise IE6 will go into quirks mode and make it near impossible to get your layout the way you want it.

[HTML doctype declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp)

Second of all...why the absolute positioning? You could just as easily have a single div like this:

```
<div style="width: 858px; margin-top: 197px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
```

Which should center the div exactly the way you want it (as long as I got everything right off the top of my head).

Comment: I really needed to use absolute due to circumstances and current condition of the website. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have the absolute positioning, I seem to recall that you can do some tricks with margin in IE6.

```
<div id="outer" style="width:100%; text-align:center">
   <div style="position:absolute; top:197px; text-align:center; width:858px; left: 50%;border:solid 1px red;margin-left:-429px;">
      My Menu
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:relative;` to your `outer` div. And, like [Justin suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180713/ie-6-bug-centering-div-tag-with-absolute-positioning/1180724#1180724), make sure you're using a DOCTYPE.

Without an example of what *should* happen and what *is* happening it's hard to give a definitive answer.